# react-native-webview: how to set initial scale for loaded website

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I'm using react-native-webview to take my users to the payment webpage. The problem is the content of the payment webpage is small, tiny at the center of the screen.
User must use his fingers to zoom in before starting using the form. I'm wondering whether it is possible to set an initial zoom level for the loaded content.

Here is my code (straight forward):

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: redirectUrl }}
/>
```

I've looked at many similar issues across the web, played with different flags (e.g scalesPageToFit), with no success.

Comment: Should we assume you only have control over the app code and not the webpage code?

Comment: yes, no control over the webpage code. This a secured payment page. I was able to "almost" fix in on android with scalesPageToFit={false}. But on ios, I still get the tiny content

Answer (score 2):

You can use `injectedJavaScript` from [React Native WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript)

```
injectedJavaScript={`
const meta = document.createElement('meta'); 
meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'); 
meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `
}
```